# How to write python decorator that updates keyword argument?

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper

The goal is to write a decorator that updates one keyword argument of the wrapped function.
In the following code wrapper attempts to update `kwarg1`:

```py
import inspect                                                                                                                                                                                         [0/300678]
from functools import wraps

def override_me(arg, kwarg1="default kwarg1", kwarg2="default kwarg2"):
    print(f"override_me {arg} kwarg1={kwarg1} kwarg2={kwarg2}")

def append_kwarg1(func):
    original_kwarg1_default = (
        inspect.signature(func).parameters["kwarg1"].default
    )

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, kwarg1=original_kwarg1_default, **kwargs):
        func(*args, kwarg1=kwarg1 + "_patched!", **kwargs)

    return wrapper

override_me = append_kwarg1(override_me)


override_me("passed_arg")
override_me("passed_arg", kwarg1="passed_kwarg1_named")
override_me("passed_arg", "passed_kwarg1_as_arg") # TypeError: override_me() got multiple values for argument 'kwarg1'
```

This, however, fails when `kwarg1` is passed as a positional argument.

Edit:
Clarifications as pointed in comments: `override_me` signature cannot be changed (think: external module).

Comment: You could try using 'kwargs.pop('kwarg1')' to remove kwarg1 from kwargs before you pass this to the function.

Comment: @scotty3785 The problem is that in the third call to override_me, the value to be overridden is in `args`, not `kwargs`. So there would be no value in `kwargs` to pop. To account for this case you would need to keep track of which arguments have which positions somehow. I'm pretty sure this can be done with the inspect module, but I haven't checked exactly how.

Comment: This seems more like an issue with how `override_me` is defined in the first place. Make `kwarg1` an keyword-only parameter so that you don't have to worry about it being specified by a positional argument at run-time.

Comment: @chepner in the real life problem that produced this question `override_me` is a third party function. That's why the question is about decorator which generally should not assume too much about the wrapped function...

Comment: You are already assuming there's a parameter called `kwarg1`; how generic does this decorator need to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution based on the fact that even a keyword argument has an index. Then depending on the length of `args` passed by caller we can determine if the argument of interest has been passed positionally or by keyword and update it either in `args` or `kwargs`:

```py
import inspect                                                                                                                                                                                         
from functools import wraps

def override_me(arg, kwarg1="default kwarg1", kwarg2="default kwarg2"):
    print(f"override_me {arg} kwarg1={kwarg1} kwarg2={kwarg2}")

def append_kwarg1(func):
    params = inspect.signature(func).parameters
    kwarg1_index = next(
        x[0] for x in zip(range(len(params)), params.items()) if x[1][0] == "kwarg1"
    )

    def update(v):
        return v + "_patched!"

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > kwarg1_index:
            args = (
                args[:kwarg1_index]
                + (update(args[kwarg1_index]),)
                + args[kwarg1_index + 1 :]
            )
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            kwargs["kwarg1"] = update(kwargs.get("kwarg1", params["kwarg1"].default))
            func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


override_me = append_kwarg1(override_me)

override_me("passed_arg", kwarg1="passed_kwarg1_named")
override_me("passed_arg")
override_me("passed_arg", "passed_kwarg1_as_arg")
override_me("passed_arg", "passed_kwarg1_as_arg", "passed_kwarg2_as_arg")
```